# Loading storyboard scene through code

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, scene

I'm very new to storyboards and objective-c in general. Basically, I have a welcome screen with 4 buttons on it. Each button loads a new scene via the `modal` way. One of the screens requires an internet connection. I have already setup the function to check to see if there is internet. If there is no connection, I'd like it to load a separate scene. It looks like this (`webView` is the name of my `UIWebView`):

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)myWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
//code
}
```

Now, the only issue I'm having is how to load the scene that it should direct to in this function. I have the feeling that I need to start by creating an outlet for this specific scene, but I'm unsure of how to even do that. I tried searching for a guide on how to do it, but it is all going over my head since I'm so new to programming. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by scene ? you mean you want to present uiviewcontroller?

Comment: Yes I think that's it, sorry I'm still learning the proper terms. Basically what I did was drag a new View Controller onto the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about `UIViewController` when you are saying `scene` the there is a rely easy way to do it, just call the following in your desired method (off course with the required name changes)

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerIdentifier"];
```

Now make sure that your storyboard has a UIViewController of type `YourViewController` and that UIViewController has `YourViewControllerIdentifier` as identifier set in the storyboard.

Now if you are talking about a custom `UIView` when you are saying `scene` then you can't do that, you can't load a custom UIView from a sotryboard without loading the proper view controller.
But you can create a custom UIView with a .xib file and load it on your desired methods.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot, I'll give that a shot now. I think it may be a custom `UIView`, basically what I did was drag a new View Controller onto the page.

Comment: I am just having one issue with it, I set the `UIViewController`'s ID, and plugged it in for `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, but I'm getting an `unused variable viewController` warning and the `UIViewController` doesn't launch. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I forgot to mention that you have to push/present modal/ or add as a child view controller the resulted view controller. Also make sure that you are setting the view controller identifier not ID

Comment: Oh cool thanks, I was setting the storyboard ID for the view controller. I'll try and figure out how to do that now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

1.) Set your project to use your storyboard inside of the project target's settings

2.) Inside storyboard, set which scene/class you want to load first by checking off the "Is Initial View Controller" property.

3.) Set up and segue through whatever other scenes/classes you have set up first

4.) Then when you reach the scene in question, have two different segues set up inside of your storyboard: one for if there's an internet connection and one if there isn't

5.) Check that condition and call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` and pass in the identifier that fulfills the internet connection critieria

Comment: Thank you that helped out a lot, I'll give that a go right now!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @ttarules I think we should merge our answers for a more complete one :))))

Comment: @danypata you want me to just add yours to mine and give you credit? haha ive never done anything like that before

Comment: @ttarules I think this would be a cool feature on SO :)). Merge 1..n answers to get a mega extra complete answer. :))

Comment: @danypata haha hell yeah thatd be awesome